# C++ DLL that uses functions of another DLL

Tags: visual-c++

I was thinking what if I build my DLL with custom stuff and DLL (core) that will contain important functions that my DLL with custom stuff uses.
Both DLLs are injected into process.
Is it possible to make core.dll give addresses of functions to custom.dll and custom.dll will use it ? Is there performance drop by doing this? Or do you prefer me to build library with symbols instead ?

Both DLLs are in C++

Comment: That is what the OS loader already does when you use a DLL built "with symbols".  The odds that a hand-crafted version of it is will be better are quite low, it is heavily micro-optimized.

Comment: So its high performance or its just waste of time by doing it, so I just put everything into one DLL, my goal is to make high performance, DLL that is doing its job fast